# Why is TinyXML2's XMLDocument::FirstChild() function returning NULL when attempting to parse this valid XML file?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I know there's probably some extremely obvious thing I'm missing here, but this has been driving me crazy for a few days now.

Here is a simple function I've written that is just supposed to find the first tag in the XML document for now:

```
void parse_weather_file(const char* weatherFileName, WeatherDataAsPWMValues *wd)
{
    if (wd == NULL) return;

    std::cout << weatherFileName << std::endl;

    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc(weatherFileName);
    tinyxml2::XMLNode *root = doc.FirstChild();
    if (root == NULL) std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the XML document I'm trying to parse:

```
<!-- Sample output of openWeatherMap API -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<current>
    <city id="2643741" name="City of London">
        <coord lon="-0.09" lat="51.51">
        <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2015-06-30T03:46:57" set="2015-06-30T20:21:12">
    </city>
    <temperature value="72.34" min="66.2" max="79.88" unit="fahrenheit"/>
    <humidity value="43" unit="%">
    <pressure value="1020" unit="hPa">
    <wind>
        <speed value="7.78" name="Moderate breeze">
        <direction value="140" code="SE" name="SouthEast">
    </wind>
    <clouds value="0" name="clear sky">
    <visibility value="10000">
    <precipitation mode="no">
    <weather number="800" value="Sky is Clear" icon="01d">
    <lastupdate value="2015-06-30T08:36:14">
</current>
```

And here is the output I get from the function:

```
test.xml
Error
```

This would suggest that `root` is NULL at the end of the function, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Comment: Your XML is not _well-formed_. Your are missing the closing slashes on the individual elements. `<lastupdate value="2015-06-30T08:36:14">`, for example, should be `<lastupdate value="2015-06-30T08:36:14" />` ( <-- see the self-closing indicator `/`).

Comment: @zx485 Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this error still occurs even with self-closing indicators on all of the single tags.

Comment: Then your XML is still *not well-formed*. So you have to look for other possible errors. I added an answer with a _well-formed_ version of your XML. See if this helps...

Comment: @zx485 This error still occurs with the following xml file: `<test><content>Hello, world</content></test>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285461/parsing-xml-files-root-nodes-has-no-child-nodes/43289066#43289066 for a discussion of `FirstChild()` versus `FirstChildElement()`

Answer (score 3):

As @zx485 explained, your XML is malformed.  But, even after fixing that, your code will still fail.  Per the [TinyXML-2 documentation](http://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/), the `tinyxml2::XMLDocument` class DOES NOT have a constructor that accepts a filename as input.  It does, however, have a constructor that accepts a `bool` as input:

```
XMLDocument( bool processEntities = true, Whitespace whitespaceMode = PRESERVE_WHITESPACE );
```

A `const char*` is implicitly convertible to a `bool`, which is why your code compiles, but you are not actually loading the file at all, which is why `root` is NULL.

You need to call the class's `LoadFile()` method instead:

```
XMLError LoadFile( const char* filename );
```

For example:

```
void parse_weather_file(const char* weatherFileName, WeatherDataAsPWMValues *wd)
{
    if (wd == NULL) return;

    std::cout << weatherFileName << std::endl;

    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;

    XMLError err = doc.LoadFile(weatherFileName);
    if (err != XML_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Error loading file: " << (int)err << std::endl;

        /* or:

        std::cout << "Error loading file: " << doc.ErrorName() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Error loading file: " << tinyxml2::XMLDocument::ErrorIDToName(err) << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Error loading file: " << doc.ErrorStr() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Error loading file" <<< endl;
        doc.PrintError();

        */

        return;
    }

    tinyxml2::XMLNode *root = doc.FirstChild();
    if (root == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error root is null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // use root as needed...
}
```

Also, you should be using the `RootElement()` method instead of the `FirstChild()` method:

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement *root = doc.RootElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

I made your XML *well-formed* by adding closing `/` on single elements.
This is how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<current>
    <city id="2643741" name="City of London">
        <coord lon="-0.09" lat="51.51" />
        <country>GB</country>
        <sun rise="2015-06-30T03:46:57" set="2015-06-30T20:21:12" />
    </city>
    <temperature value="72.34" min="66.2" max="79.88" unit="fahrenheit" />
    <humidity value="43" unit="%" />
    <pressure value="1020" unit="hPa" />
    <wind>
        <speed value="7.78" name="Moderate breeze" />
        <direction value="140" code="SE" name="SouthEast" />
    </wind>
    <clouds value="0" name="clear sky" />
    <visibility value="10000" />
    <precipitation mode="no" />
    <weather number="800" value="Sky is Clear" icon="01d" />
    <lastupdate value="2015-06-30T08:36:14" />
</current>
```

Hope this helps you identifying errors...